# Extract tag info from XML files to Excel file

Tags: xml, excel, perl, vba, parsing

I have close to 100 XML files containing various stored procedure names within the tag . Each file may contain more than one SP or the same repeating again.

```
    <DataSourceName>SQL300</DataSourceName>
    <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
    <CommandText>dbDummy.dbo.abc456Audit </CommandText>
```

I took over a project to migrate the SQL server data to SAS grid and all SSRS reports to SAS. I will have to map all the data.

Is there any easy Linux/perl/VBA/Python way to do this in one step? 
I wanted something like:

```
File Name    Stored Procedures
Audit93       dbDummy.dbo.abc456Audit
Audit93       dbDummy.dbo.abc123Audit
```

I tried: grep, sed, awk, perl, VBA .

methods described here and in other places. I could able to extract all the tag info into one flat file, but nothing close to what I was looking for above. I need some technique to extract the file name along with the tags.

I would appreciate if someone can shed some lights on how to approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear the relation between the output and the input...

Comment: Sorry, basically I wanted to extract the info between the tag <CommandText>dbDummy.dbo.abc456Audit </CommandText> and put them into excel file for each XML file. I want some indicator for the XML file name on the excel file.

Comment: So finally you need xml filename in first row and data between <Commandtext> in the second row to be placed in the excel file. Repeat this for all 100 xml files and place it in the same excel file ? Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Exactly, thanks for clarifying my question.

Comment: Do you need anything more than CSV output (which Excel will import) or do you want more control than that

Comment: I presume there are other `CommandType` values than `StoredProcedure`? You will need to show a more representative sample of the XML

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $dir = $ARGV[0];

opendir(DIR, "$dir") || die "Couldn't open the directory - $!";

my @files = grep(/\.xml$/,readdir(DIR));
my $OutFile = "Output". "\." . "xlsx";
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($OutFile);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('SotredProcedures');
# Create a format for the column headings
my $header = $workbook->add_format();
$header->set_bold();
$header->set_color('red');
# Create a Text Wrap format
my $format1 = $workbook->add_format();
$format1->set_text_wrap();


$worksheet->write(0, 0, "Filenames", $header);
$worksheet->write(0, 1, "Stored Procedures", $header);
$worksheet->set_column(0, 1, 12);
$worksheet->set_column(1, 2, 100);

my $row=1;
foreach our $filename (@files){
    my $document = do {
         local $/ = undef;
         open my $fh,'<',$filename or die "Couldn't open the file $filename:$!";
       <$fh>;
      };


      my $checkval = "false";
      while($document =~ /<CommandText>(.*?)<\/CommandText>/isg)
         {
             if($1 ne "")
              {
               $checkval = "true";
               $worksheet->write($row,0,$filename,$format1); 
               $worksheet->write($row,1,$1,$format1);
               $row++;
                  }
              }
         if($checkval eq "false")
           {
              print "No <CommandText> Value in $filename\n";
              }   

        }
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the perl script. When I tried, it seems like the Excel::Writer::XLSX is not installed in the ksh. I am trying to see how to install and then try this out.

Answer (score 0):

@Praveen' Perl solution is better (more robust, and produces richer excel);

Following a simple command to build a tab-separated-value that
probably will do the job:

```
( 
  echo -e "file\tSP" ;
  grep -PoH '(?<=<CommandText>).*?(?=<)' *.xml | tr ':' '\t' 
) > stored_proc.tsv
```

If you prefer a `xls` file:

```
ssconvert stored_proc.tsv stored_proc.xls
```

Finally see the result with excel, gnumeric, whatever...

```
gnumeric stored_proc.tsv
```

Comment: I installed the packages, but MakeMaker is not finding Excel::Writer::XLSX and vice versa as they have installed in different places. Since I never worked on perl before, I am searching online to get this resolved so that I can try the script above. Thanks!

Comment: @user2939050, my solution is not using Excel::Writer::XLSX; Perl modules in general can be installed by `sudo cpan Excel::Writer::XLSX`. What is you operating system etc?

Comment: I could not able to install the packages right even after several try. I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago). The above JJoao solution did not work.     was getting 
suexec: Program cpan not found
error

Comment: JJoao....Many thanks for the script. I tried running in sh, it worked and it created the tsv file within 1 sec. I was thinking all along it is a perl script. I used python to convert to csv and opened it in excel. It worked fine, I got exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: user2939050, in order to have @Praveen solution working (be careful Praveen will not be notified about the comments you are writing under my answer) you need Perl working properly :)  -- suggestion : `sudo yum install perl-CPAN` to have cpan command (used to install perl modules); Please try also  `sudo yum install perl-Excel-Writer-XLSX`

Comment: `sudo yum install gnumeric` can be used to install gnumeric (excel like) spreadsheet and also `ssconvert` converter tool.  Spreadsheets normally open `.tsv` dierectly.